# Disk is apparently in use by the system

Tags: mount, software-raid

I've just fitted two disks to my home server. I'm trying to format and then raid them but I'm getting a problem that hours of Googling hasn't resolved this.

The error that I'm getting is:

```
# mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1
  mke2fs 1.39 (29-May-2006)
  /dev/sdb1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!

# df -h
  Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/sda1             4.0G  1.9G  2.0G  49% /
  none                  380M     0  380M   0% /dev/shm
  /opt/xensource/packages/iso/XenCenter.iso
                        51M   51M     0 100% /var/xen/xc-install

# mount -t ext3 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/b
  mount: /dev/sdb1 already mounted or /mnt/b busy
```

I'm new to this and it's got me beat. I wouldn't ask if I hadn't done my research first. Thanks.

```
# mount
  /dev/sda1 on / type ext3 (rw)
  none on /proc type proc (rw)
  none on /sys type sysfs (rw)
  none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw)
  none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
  /opt/xensource/packages/iso/XenCenter.iso on /var/xen/xc-install type iso9660 (ro,loop=/dev/loop0)
  none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
  sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)

# mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
  mdadm: chunk size defaults to 64K
  mdadm: Cannot open /dev/sdb1: Device or resource busy
  mdadm: /dev/sdc1 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
    size=976760000K  mtime=Tue Jul 10 21:52:00 2012
  mdadm: create aborted

# cat /proc/swaps
  Filename              Type        Size    Used    Priority
  /var/swap/swap.001                      file      524280  0   -1
```

Comment: Please add output of `mount` w/o parameters

Comment: Also add the output of `lsof|grep "/mnt/b"`

Comment: Why are you trying to format, and **then** raid?  Normally you setup the partition/raid/volume and then the filesystem.

Comment: @Alex I've added the mount w/o params.

Comment: @TomO'Connor I tried the command you gave but lsof shows command not found.

Comment: @Zoredache I'm sorry, like I said, I'm new to this. However, the same problem exists when I tried to create the RAID. I've updated to include this also.

Comment: @Shaun Please also add output of `cat /proc/swaps`, I bet `/dev/sdb1` is a swap partition.

Comment: Looks like his system is automounting the drives, which tends to limit the abilities of mkfs and others.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've run

```
# dmsetup remove /dev/mapper/[device]
```

and that has let me run

```
# mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdcmdadm: size set to 976762496K
  mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
```

Then I've run

```
# mkfs.ext3 /dev/md0
```

Which again has worked as expected.

Comment: Whew, I was facing a similar issue!
I installed a new NVME SSD on my server. Partitioned it using fdisk, then tried to create ext4 filesystem for it. But then ran into the same issue you were facing. (removing the symlink in /dev/mapper/

I did not create any logical volume and I could not list any  logical volumes present in my partition. 
Any idea how it could have been created?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

What type of RAID are you using (LVM, md, Hardware...)? Typically you need to build the RAID prior to actually formatting.

Additionally as @tom-oconnor and @alex mentioned output would be appreciated

Comment: I've updated to show those outputs. I'm new to this and I'm trying to feel my way around. I've also added the output when I tried to create the raid.

Comment: Ok, so you need to clear the partition from sdb and sdc using parted or fdisk. Once that is done you should be clear to build the RAID

Comment: thanks. I've cleared the partitions but I still get this error: "mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
mdadm: chunk size defaults to 64K
mdadm: Cannot open /dev/sdb: Device or resource busy
mdadm: create aborted"

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb bs=1M status=progress
```

This command will delete the metadata and digital signatures which is even caused by Intel VROC (virtual raid on CPU), but takes more time depending on the size of hard disk.